# .dbx to .pst converter software recommendation for Outlook 2013

Tags: windows, outlook

I need a dbx to pst converter tool that will help me to migrate my wife’s emails in old laptop to new Dell laptop latitude 3540 with Windows 8 pre-installed and MS Office 2013 configured.

gone through [this Microsoft article](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_xp-networking/converting-dbx-from-outlook-express-to-outlook-pst/654d5d6a-baa4-41c8-b981-9aa0b468fc65) but it didn't helped much.

There are bunch of dbx file in the mail folder(e.g folder.dbx, inbox.dbx, offline.dbx etc.) that i want all to get relocate to Outlook 2013.

[image]

Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at [this dbx to pst converter](http://www.freeviewer.org/outlook-express/dbx-to-pst.html) and going by what the developer says on their website you will be able to transfer all your Outlook Express mail in your Outlook 2013.

Note: Make sure you use their trial version first as they are offering some limited transfer capability Then try to attach that converted .pst file in your Outlook.

For information *how to attach pst in Outlook 2013*, you can go through the [MS support article.](https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/Open-Outlook-Data-Files-pst-381b776d-7511-45a0-953a-0935c79d24f2)

Answer (score 0):

Going Though web doing a bit of research,The most recommended software seems to be for this requirement,[DBX to PST Converter by SysInfoTools](http://www.sysinfotools.com/recovery/dbx-to-pst-converter.html).A basic introduction from the official website as mentioned below.

> *SysInfoTools DBX to PST Converter is an advanced way to perform*
>   *conversion of multiple DBX files of Outlook Express into Outlook PST*
>   *format. It takes only one click and all the selected DBX files are*
>   *converted into PST format. If you are looking for a way to perform*
>   *batch conversion of DBX files, this would be the best option you can*
>   *choose*.
>   **This tool generates a new PST file in which all the selected DBX files are merged. The new converted PST file can be saved at user-defined location with a new name. It allows users to add new PST file to their Outlook profile. Users are also enabled to apply password on their new PST file for protection. This tool supports DBX files which are created in any version of Outlook Express and runs smoothly under all major Windows operating systems**

**Operating System: Windows 7, Windows Vista, Windows XP, Windows 2008, 2003, 2000, NT and 98.
Memory: Minimum 256 MB (512 MB recommended).
Disk Space: No temporary file is created.
To save converted output, make sure MS Outlook is installed on your system.**

---

### Free Demo Version Limitation

*Demo version of the software contains all the functionalities. But there is only one limitation; software will convert only 25 emails per DBX file into PST file. Through this you wan check software capablity and its speed as well as accuracy but if you want to convert all emails of all DBX files then you need to buy the full version of the software.*

### Features of SysInfoTools DBX to PST Converter

- Batch Conversion: It performs batch conversion of DBX files into PST
  format at a time. Converting multiple DBX files into PST format one
  by one is a tedious task to perform. You can select multiple files
  simultaneously using this tool.
- Password-protection: By using this tool, users can apply
  password-protection to the new PST file (generated by the tool). You
  can set any type of password (alphanumeric and multilingual) for the
  PST file before starting the conversion process.
- Search files: The search file option will allow user to search the
  DBX files from the system automatically. This feature is useful when
  a user does not know the exact location of the DBX files in the
  system.
- Saves Output at Desired Location: The output, i.e. PST file, which is
  generated after the conversion process of DBX files into PST format,
  can be used at user-defined location with a new name.
- Quick and Efficient: The conversion process of DBX files into PST
  format is performed very quickly without taking much time. It does
  not cause any changes or alteration to the original files. The
  original DBX files are remained intact or unchanged.
- **Wide support and compatibility: The tool provides wide supports for
  the DBX files which are created in any version of Outlook Express,
  such as: 5.0, 5.01, 5.5 and 6.0. It is highly compatible with all
  major versions of Windows operating systems.**
- Add PST to Outlook profile: The new PST file, which is generated by this tool, can easily be added to MS Outlook profile directly from here before starting the conversion process.
- Easy-to-Use Application: This is an easy-to-use tool that requires no technical expertise. It works in a self-describing mode that enables non-technical users to perform DBX to PST conversion with ease.

**Hope I have found the right solution for your problem!**